# Is there a way to pass a parameter known only at run time to an object created by getit dependency injection?

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection, widget, bloc

Is there a way to pass a parameter known only at run time to an object created by getit dependency injection when the object is being created or retrieved from a Dependency Injector?

```dart
class WatchVideoPage extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: () => locator<WatchVideoPageBloc>(), // I want the bloc to know of the videoId.
      child: new RandomWidget()
    );
  }

  final VideoId videoId;
}
```

'locator' is the dependency injection thing in the code.

Or is there another way of making the bloc know the value of videoId?

Thanks!

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/get_it#:~:text=Passing%20Parameters%20to,for%20registering%20factories%3A
Check this section.

Answer (score 2):

You can just create an event that makes the video ID known to the bloc:

```
create: () => locator<WatchVideoPageBloc>()..add(StartStreaming(videoId)),
```

Obviously, that means you need an event called `StartStreaming` that takes a `VideoId`  in their constructor.

Comment: That's what I thought of too, but Is it commonly done this way? Multiple events will want to know the videoid so should I pass out through each event?

Comment: If there's any other way please tell me soon or Ill mark this as the answer. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: You mean state? Yes, if each state needs the video id, then each state should have a property video id.

Comment: I mean when mapping an event to state, a lot of the events will be using the video id. Is passing it through the event the best way for this?